# Repeat rows of a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to repeat it n times while preserving the original order of the rows:

```
>>>a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Desired ouput (for n =2):

```
>>>a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

I found a np.repeat function, however, it doesnt preserve the original order of the columns. Is there any other in-built function or a trick that will repeat the array while preserving the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way of doing it. I have also added some time comparison against @coldspeed's solution

```
n = 2
a_new = np.tile(a.flatten(), n) 
a_new.reshape((n*a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

**Performance comparison with coldspeed's solution**

**My method** for n = 10000

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
n = 10000

def tile_flatten(a, n):
    a_new = np.tile(a.flatten(), n).reshape((n*a.shape[0], a.shape[1])) 
    return a_new

%timeit tile_flatten(a,n)
# 149 µs ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**coldspeed's solution 1** for n = 10000

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
n = 10000

def concatenate_repeat(a, n):
    a_new =  np.concatenate(np.repeat(a[None, :], n, axis=0), axis=0)
    return a_new

%timeit concatenate_repeat(a,n)
# 7.61 ms ± 1.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**coldspeed's solution 2** for n = 10000

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
n = 10000

def broadcast_reshape(a, n):
    a_new =  np.broadcast_to(a, (n, *a.shape)).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
    return a_new

%timeit broadcast_reshape(a,n)
# 162 µs ± 29.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**@user2357112's solution**

```
def tile_only(a, n):
    a_new = np.tile(a, (n, 1))
    return a_new

%timeit tile_only(a,n)
# 142 µs ± 21.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: The tuple should probably be `(n, 1)` instead of `(2, 1)` in your test of my answer.

Comment: @user2357112: Oh yes, thanks for noticing. I was surprised to see an order of magnitude difference. Now I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), followed by [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
np.concatenate(np.repeat(a[None, :], n, axis=0), axis=0)

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

---

Another option is to use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
np.broadcast_to(a, (n, *a.shape)).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Sorry,I did a mistake in the desired output, its dimension was wrong.

Comment: @coldspeed: Is reshape inefficient here?

Comment: @Bazingaa I don't think so, it only changes the array's strides (the data doesn't change).

Comment: @Bazingaa You should actually use `timeit` (not `time`) to time statements. I've added a much faster solution, but I think yours is a bit faster.

Comment: @coldspeed: Thanks for the reply. Using timeit would require putting things in a function, right?

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes, unless you have IPython, in which case you can use `%timeit` for single line statements, and `%%timeit` for multiline.

Comment: @coldspeed: Please have a look now and see if I am using timeit correctly. I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: @coldspeed: Overall, you second solution is comparable to mine.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.repeat` is for repetition on an element-wise basis. For repeating the array as a whole, you want [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

```
numpy.tile(a, (2, 1))
```

The tuple is the number of repetitions in each axis. You want 2 in the first and 1 in the second, so the tuple is `(2, 1)`.

Comment: I would like to add the timings of your solution to my answer for completeness sake highlighting the novelty of your answer. May I do it?

Comment: @Bazingaa: Go ahead.

Comment: I added it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is one case where the fill pattern for `np.resize` is useful:

```
In [82]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [83]: np.resize(arr,(6,4))
Out[83]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

(The `resize` method is different.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [numpy.tile()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

This is how you can use **numpy.tile**  to repeat your array while saving the original order:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

n = 5
b = np.tile(a, (n,1))
print b
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
b=np.append(a,a).reshape(np.shape(a)[0]*2,np.shape(a)[1])
```

Output

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```